# Comparing expressions with eval function

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I have write code in Python 3 in the following format :

- def function1()
- def function2()
- def function3()
- def main()

Then I call the main :

main()

The function eval() it's into my main() also.
The purpose of my code is to getting two expressions and returns whether they are equals or not.
For example :

- answer = """ A ← A * 3"""
- my_input = """ A ← 3 * A"""

Comparing these expressions the result must be "Equals" ( or True ).

I'm getting the error below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "my_path", line 218, in <module>
    main()
File "my_path", line 200, in main
if eval(a) == eval(b) and eval(c) == eval(d) :
File "<string>", line 2

  ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Do I need to import something ?
Or to re-arrange the functions ?
I'm here to understand, not to solve the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Your function has the character ← in it? That's obviously not going to work.

Comment: I'm using the split method to get the part before and after the arrow. Then I compare them respectively.

Comment: Post the entire code please, it seems you're getting a `SyntaxError`, your file is ending too soon.

Comment: Possibly missing a quote somewhere.

Comment: could you please add your code. It looks like the if statement hasn't been used correctly

Comment: I've found the issue, thanks guys. Needed ` ''.join(str(ord(char)))` instead of just ` ".join(char)` in order to make use of eval function.